# What is the "initial shift state"?

Tags: c++, c, file, initialization, character

In the standard, the term of the "initial shift state" is often cited, also seemingly in various contexts, such as multibyte characters(strings) and files. But the standard missed an explanation of what this exactly shall be.

What is that? And what is a "shift" here in general?

Also:

Because of the term for me seems to be used in different contexts( in the context of characters, in the context of strings and in the context of files), I will point to a few text phrases from the standard (especially ISO/IEC:9899/2018 (C18)) which include the term of "initial shift state":

> § 5.2.1.2 - Multibyte characters
>
> — A multibyte character set may have a state-dependent encoding, wherein each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an **initial shift state** and enters other locale-specific shift states when specific multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence.
>
> — An identifier, comment, string literal, character constant, or header name shall begin and end in the **initial shift state**.
>
> ---
>
> § 7.21.3 - Files
>
> "— A file need not begin nor end in the **initial shift state**.274)"
>
> "274)Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the **initial shift state**."
>
> ---
>
> §7.21.6.2 - The fscanf function
>
> For the `s` conversion specifier:
>
> "If an l length modifier is present, the input shall be a sequence of multibyte characters that begins in the **initial shift state**."

- What is meant by the "inital shift state"? What is that?
- What is a "shift" in context?
- Is it in the context of strings the double quotation mark `"` which is the beginning and end of a format string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) for a discussion of a character set with shift states.  It basically means that a byte such as 0x40 has different meanings depending on the prior context (whether the data is in the shift state or not).

Answer (score 2):

A shift state refers to a state which informs the interpretation of some byte sequence as characters, this is encoding dependent.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Shift-State.html

> In some multibyte character codes, the meaning of any particular byte
>   sequence is not fixed; it depends on what other sequences have come
>   earlier in the same string. Typically there are just a few sequences
>   that can change the meaning of other sequences; these few are called
>   shift sequences and we say that they set the shift state for other
>   sequences that follow.
>
> To illustrate shift state and shift sequences, suppose we decide that
>   the sequence 0200 (just one byte) enters Japanese mode, in which pairs
>   of bytes in the range from 0240 to 0377 are single characters, while
>   0201 enters Latin-1 mode, in which single bytes in the range from 0240
>   to 0377 are characters, and interpreted according to the ISO Latin-1
>   character set. This is a multibyte code that has two alternative shift
>   states (“Japanese mode” and “Latin-1 mode”), and two shift sequences
>   that specify particular shift states.

The initial shift state is just the shift state initially, i.e. at the start of processing; in the example above it would be whichever of ISO Latin-1 or Japanese the sequence in question begins in.